# Force PHPUnit test to throw exception

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

I'm very new to unit testing in general and PHPUnit in particular, so please forgive me if this is a simple question. I have done some googling, but I don't know enough to know what to search for.

So I have a function:

```
function convert_timezone($dt, $tzFrom, $tzTo, $format) {
    $newDate = '';

    $tzFromFull = timezone_name_from_abbr($tzFrom);
    $tzToFull = timezone_name_from_abbr($tzTo);

    if( $tzFromFull != $tzToFull ) {
        $dtFrom = new DateTimeZone($tzFromFull);
        $dtTo = new DateTimeZone($tzToFull);

        try {
            // find the offsets from GMT for the 2 timezones
            $current = new DateTime(date('c',$dt));
            $offset1 = $dtFrom->getOffset($current);
            $offset2 = $dtTo->getOffset($current);
            $offset = $offset2 - $offset1;

            // apply the offset difference to the current time
            $newDate = date($format, $current->format('U') + $offset);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $newDate = date($format.' (T)', $dt);
        }
    } else {
        $newDate = date($format, $dt);
    }

    return $newDate;
}
```

Here's the test function:

```
function test_convert_timezone() {
   $dt = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2000);
   $tzFrom = 'CDT';
   $tzTo = 'EDT';
   $format = 'd/m/Y g:i a';
   $result = convert_timezone($dt, $tzFrom, $tzTo, $format);
   $this->assertEquals($result, '01/01/2000 1:00 am');
}
```

When I run the tests directly in Netbeans, the test passes. But when I use the command-line option to generate a code coverage report, it tells me that this function is not completely covered because the test isn't hitting the exception.

I know if I could alter the original function, I could force it to throw an error. But I can't do that. I need a way, in the test function, to pass something in that will make the function being tested hit its exception. Where do I start?

Comment: Erm... what if you just create another test with data that will cause DateTime to throw an exception, then check for the expected result (of statements in `catch` block) with PHPUnit?

Comment: We're implementing unit testing on a site that's already built, so no - we can't write code based on the tests. As far as  writing another test, as I said - I'm very new at this. Is it kosher to have more than one test function for a single function being tested?

Comment: Of course. If your function has branches, how can you check for all of them in a single test? It's not ok to have multiple asserts in a single test, as it defeats the principle of test isolation (check the discussion started by [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1962358/tdd-why-is-there-only-one-test-per-function) for details on that).

Comment: OK, I'm confused. If I write a test that specifically designed to throw an error, won't that make the test fail? How do I write a test where the "success" result is predicated on the actual function failing?

Comment: Well, you actually can check for exceptions (with `@expectedException` annotation, for example) in PHPUnit tests. But the point is, you don't have to do this, as your function doesn't throw exceptions - it handles them with `$newDate = date($format.' (T)', $dt);` line. Now your task is to make the test that will hit this line - that is, will cause `new DateTime` to throw an exception.

Comment: I guess that's where I'm stuck. I didn't write the function in the first place, and I can't seem to find anything that will cause it to throw the exception. I get errors if I pass in invalid data, but nothing that actually forces it into the catch block.

Comment: Ah, now I see. The problem is, `date` function is quite... resistant - it returns either a valid datetime string or `false`. Both values are happily consumed by `DateTime` constructor. Still, this code is fragile, as _any_ non-numeric value `$dt` will cause `E_WARNING` in `date` - not captured by `try-catch`, as it's not an exception. You can test for errors as well, of course, but it won't help here...

Answer (score 1):

You are pretty much not able to test that branch as the code stands.

Your try-catch block doesn't actually catch any exceptions. (`date` throws an error which isn't caught.  `getOffset` doesn't either)  Ironically `new DateTimeZone` can if you pass in a timezone constant that isn't appropriate  [DateTimeZone::__construct()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetimezone.construct.php).  So if you can refactor it and pass in timezones that are not listed as valid you can get the exception (which you should as it seems that it is your intention to catch the exceptions here).

```
function convert_timezone($dt, $tzFrom, $tzTo, $format) {
    $newDate = '';

    $tzFromFull = timezone_name_from_abbr($tzFrom);
    $tzToFull = timezone_name_from_abbr($tzTo);

    if( $tzFromFull != $tzToFull ) {
        try {
            $dtFrom = new DateTimeZone($tzFromFull);
            $dtTo = new DateTimeZone($tzToFull);


            // find the offsets from GMT for the 2 timezones
            $current = new DateTime(date('c',$dt));
            $offset1 = $dtFrom->getOffset($current);
            $offset2 = $dtTo->getOffset($current);
            $offset = $offset2 - $offset1;

            // apply the offset difference to the current time
            $newDate = date($format, $current->format('U') + $offset);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $newDate = date($format.' (T)', $dt);
        }
    } else {
        $newDate = date($format, $dt);
    }

    return $newDate;
}
```

Then the test would be

```
function test_convert_timezone() {
   $dt = mktime(0,0,0,1,1,2000);
   $tzFrom = 'foo';
   $tzTo = 'EDT';
   $format = 'd/m/Y g:i a';
   $result = convert_timezone($dt, $tzFrom, $tzTo, $format);
   $this->assertEquals($result, '01/01/2000 1:00 am');
}
```

In this test, `timezone_name_from_abbr` will return `false` which will cause the `DateTimeZone` constructor to throw an exception reaching your branch.

IMO, you want to avoid constructing objects that you are going to use in your functions.  For this code, I would pass in the two DateTimeZone objects as well as a DateTime object and perform the operations on them.  Moving the creation of these other objects into a different function/class.  This way you could mock the DateTimeZone and DateTime objects themselves and have more control over what is happening.  This code it isn't too bad but it can cause trouble with trying to test other things.

Also, be careful about catching a generic exception in your code.  If you are using a mock object in a try-catch block, your code can catch a FailedTestException (thrown when a mock is not called with the right parameters or similar) which will be caught by your code.  Making it look like your test is passing when it actually isn't.  Again not a problem here due to the code and the lack of mocks but I wanted to make you aware of it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'll keep it in mind for the future. Unfortunately for this round of testing, we are unable to change our source code at all. We need to write the tests to cover the code as it stands.